# Nested SSH session with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm rewriting a Bash script I wrote into Python. The crux of that script was

```
ssh -t first.com "ssh second.com very_remote_command"
```

I'm having a problem with the nested authentication with paramiko. I wasn't able to find any examples dealing with my precise situation, but I was able to find examples with *sudo* on a remote host.

[The first method](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/) writes to stdin

```
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='jesse', password='lol')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo dmesg")
stdin.write('lol\n')
stdin.flush()
```

[The second](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/765465) creates a channel and uses the socket-like *send* and *recv*.

I was able to get *stdin.write* to work with *sudo*, but it doesn't work with *ssh* on the remote host.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('first.com', username='luser', password='secret')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ssh luser@second.com')
stdin.write('secret')
stdin.flush()
print '---- out ----'
print stdout.readlines()
print '---- error ----'
print stderr.readlines()

ssh.close()
```

...prints...

```
---- out ----
[]
---- error ----
['Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.\r\n', 'Permission denied, please try again.\r\n', 'Permission denied, please try again.\r\n', 'Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).\r\n']
```

The pseudo-terminal error reminded me of the -t flag in my original command, so I switched to the second method, using a Channel. Instead of ssh.exec_command and later, I have:

```
t = ssh.get_transport()
chan = t.open_session()
chan.get_pty()
print '---- send ssh cmd ----'
print chan.send('ssh luser@second.com')
print '---- recv ----'
print chan.recv(9999)
chan = t.open_session()
print '---- send password ----'
print chan.send('secret')
print '---- recv ----'
print chan.recv(9999)
```

...but it prints '---- send ssh cmd ----' and just hangs until I kill the process.

I'm new to Python and none too knowledgeable about networks. In the first case, why does sending the password work with *sudo* but not with *ssh*? Are the prompts different? Is paramiko even the right library for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, but it requires a little manual work. If anyone have a better solution, please tell me.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('first.com', username='luser', password='secret')

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()

# Ssh and wait for the password prompt.
chan.send('ssh second.com\n')
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('\'s password: '):
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    buff += resp

# Send the password and wait for a prompt.
chan.send('secret\n')
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('some-prompt$ '):
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    buff += resp

# Execute whatever command and wait for a prompt again.
chan.send('ls\n')
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('some-prompt$ '):
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    buff += resp

# Now buff has the data I need.
print 'buff', buff

ssh.close()
```

The thing to note is that instead of this

```
t = ssh.get_transport()
chan = t.open_session()
chan.get_pty()
```

...you want this

```
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
```

It reminds me of when I tried to write a TradeWars script when I was a kid and gave up coding for ten years. :)

Comment: i am trying to use your solution for a similar need..However ('some-prompt$ ') is not always fixed..it always has a '#' but some other content which keeps varying..how do i account for it ?

Comment: If it ends with `#`, then change `some-prompt$ ` to `#`. However, make sure that you check for trailing white space, i.e. `...endswith('# ')` isn't the same as `...endswith('#')`.

Comment: would the expect utility (a TCL thing) help you out? The python equivalent is pexpect I believe...

Comment: I had this problem while working at a place that had no deployment procedure. I had to cat files from the production servers through a bastion host just to see what was deployed. For the past six years I've been working at places that deploy versions of code instead of a will-he nil-he deployment free-for-all. (People would literal chose which files to deploy from any version of the codebase and everyone had permission to do it.) I don't need to nest ssh sessions anymore because I can put my script on a remote host and run it there if I want.

Comment: Also I'm smarter. I'm pretty sure I could have done this with an ssh command. Probably at the time I didn't understand the three levels of escaping that would need to be done.

Comment: Set `chan.settimeout(3)` after invoking shell command if your `while` hangs and handle `socket.timeout` exception.

Comment: @mqsoh what is resp = chan.recv(9999) ?

Comment: @Praneeth: `chan` is some type of socket, so `recv` just takes an arbitrary amount of data. In the docs I found out that I should of used a power of 2. Also, there's a pointless assignment. Nowadays I would have done `buff += chan.recv(4096)`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv

Answer (score 17):

Here is a small example using paramiko only (and port forwarding):

```
import paramiko as ssh

class SSHTool():
    def __init__(self, host, user, auth,
                 via=None, via_user=None, via_auth=None):
        if via:
            t0 = ssh.Transport(via)
            t0.start_client()
            t0.auth_password(via_user, via_auth)
            # setup forwarding from 127.0.0.1:<free_random_port> to |host|
            channel = t0.open_channel('direct-tcpip', host, ('127.0.0.1', 0))
            self.transport = ssh.Transport(channel)
        else:
            self.transport = ssh.Transport(host)
        self.transport.start_client()
        self.transport.auth_password(user, auth)

    def run(self, cmd):
        ch = self.transport.open_session()
        ch.set_combine_stderr(True)
        ch.exec_command(cmd)
        retcode = ch.recv_exit_status()
        buf = ''
        while ch.recv_ready():
            buf += ch.recv(1024)
        return (buf, retcode)

# The example below is equivalent to
# $ ssh 10.10.10.10 ssh 192.168.1.1 uname -a
# The code above works as if these 2 commands were executed:
# $ ssh -L <free_random_port>:192.168.1.1:22 10.10.10.10
# $ ssh 127.0.0.1:<free_random_port> uname -a
host = ('192.168.1.1', 22)
via_host = ('10.10.10.10', 22)

ssht = SSHTool(host, 'user1', 'pass1',
    via=via_host, via_user='user2', via_auth='pass2')

print ssht.run('uname -a')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on which port you're forwarding and what host is doing the forwarding in your example?

Comment: Added a comment in the code and did a small change re. forwarding.

Comment: User1 and pass1 are for target and vía are for the first host.  Thanks Sina.

Answer (score 7):

You can create ssh connection using channel from another ssh connection. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039769) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks. It's the best method I have found.

Comment: This is the best and should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a ready made solution check out pxssh from the pxpect project. Look at the sshls.py and ssh_tunnel.py examples.

http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect

Comment: pexpect is now not supported on windows

Answer (score 0):

Sinas's answer works well but didn't provide all the output from very long commands for me.  However, using chan.makefile() allows me to retrieve all the output.

The below works on a system that requires tty and also prompts for sudo password

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.10.10.1", 22, "user", "password")
chan=ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.get_pty()
f = chan.makefile()
chan.exec_command("sudo dmesg")
chan.send("password\n")
print f.read()
ssh.close()
```