# Can I get the exit code of a command executed in a subshell via ssh?

Tags: ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to use Paramiko to write a deployment script, and I'm having trouble with exit codes from the commands I run. I'm using code similar to that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko/1916877#1916877), but it's a little more complicated. Basically, from our dev boxes we have to go through a jump server, and from there to a series of production machines. Once there we have to switch to a system user (sudo su - systemuser) and then we can run commands.

The problem is that as I understand it I have 3 subshells - the ssh session, the nested ssh command and then the su subshell. I can't get Paramiko to give me back the exit code of the commands in the inner subshell - I guess the exit code it will eventually return will be that of the ssh command. I suspect this problem is not actually specific to Paramiko - does the SSH protocol even support this kind of usage?

I'm currently always executing:

```
(my command); echo "Process terminated with exit code $?"
```

and then parsing this out on the client, but it's pretty ugly - is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I guess the exit code it will eventually return will be that of the ssh command. I suspect this problem is not actually specific to Paramiko - does the SSH protocol even support this kind of usage?

Yes, and no.

The exit status is always returned, but it may not be from where you think. Once you call `invoke_shell()`, your remote process is a shell, probably bash. The `exit_status` you receive will be the one from that shell, *not* any of the processes it ran. Paramiko (nor any ssh implementation) can ever return the exit status of your commands, because the exit statuses are never seen outside of that remote shell. It's up to you to determine what your exit status should be, and exit the shell with `exit $EXIT_STATUS` (often `exit $?` is enough)

If you can break up your commands, or wrap them in a script, then use the `exec_command()` method, you will have access to the correct exit status directly.

Alternatively, you can use shell command `exec` in the remote shell, and the shell's process will be replaced by the command called by exec, and its exit status will be returned.

All three of these methods will set the `channel.exit_status` attribute as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that's what I suspected. The reason I'm using `invoke_shell()` is that I want to run various commands on the server without recreating the connection. I have to go through a jump box, so from Paramiko I use `connect()` (to the jump box), `invoke_shell()` then execute `ssh <server>`. Once there I have to switch to a system user (`sudo su - <user>`), then I'd like to be able to execute various commands without having to re-do all of the above, but still retrieving the return codes. Is this possible?

Comment: @Colin - Yes, using the techniques I show above. It's up to you to transfer the return codes you want back up the chain, either by `exit`'ing the shell with the correct status, or by `exec`'ing the command you want directly.

Comment: but that only allows me to return the exit code of a single command per session (since `exec` replaces the current process). I'd then have to re-connect between each command, correct?

Comment: @Colin - yes, you only get the last exit code, the one returned by the shell/remote-process. This is just how a shell works, and has nothing to do with ssh. Since you're looking for exit_status, I assume you're scripting these commands; why not send the logic to the remote machine in a python/shell script, where you can have direct access to the commands? Otherwise, break up the commands, and use the ssh channel like an RPC mechanism, where you can effectively ignore the "shell" portion.

Comment: I start the shell with -eu so the shell bombs out as soon as there is a problem.  Something like this: `echo 'set -eu ; cd wherever ; do something' | ssh host bash` or `echo "false ; echo haha" | ssh host sudo -u dudekins sh -eu`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a problem where the man page for 'ssh' says that it returns the exit code of the process it runs, but I can't seem to get it to return a non-zero error code.  From the ssh man page:

```
 The session terminates when the command or shell on the remote machine
 exits and all X11 and TCP/IP connections have been closed.  The exit sta‐
 tus of the remote program is returned as the exit status of ssh.
```

That doesn't seem to be true.

But I would try something like this and see what happens on your system.

```
% ssh localhost bash -c "exit 3" ; echo $?
0
```

When I run a similar command locally, bash returns an exit code.

```
% bash -c 'exit 3' ; echo $?
3
```

The double quotes will be removed before ssh seems the commands however.
So let's try more quotes.

```
% ssh localhost bash -c "'exit 3'" ; echo $?
3
```

Bingo.   The "exit 3" was turning into "exit" followed by an ignored word
on the bash command line.  So bash was running the command "exit".

Unfortunately for me, I think this whole answer is a digression
from the original questions and doesn't contain enough merit as
a question in its own right.  So thanks everyone for helping me
answer by secondary question (not related to the original question).

Comment: That's weird, I get the same result. I'd expected ssh, at least, to return a sensible exit code. I have no idea what's happening there.

Comment: I just tried this with a command that directly returns an error code, and that works correctly: `ssh localhost "ls blarg"; echo $?` correctly returns an error code. I think in your example the `exit` subshell returns 3 to bash, but bash returns 0 (because it terminates correctly).

Comment: I get the same: `ssh localhost bash -c "exit 3" ` returns 0.  `echo 'exit 3' | ssh localhost bash` returns 3.  Surprisingly this also returns 0: `ssh localhost bash -eu -c "exit 3"`