# python paramiko ssh

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

i'm new on python. i wrote a script to connect to a host and execute one command

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=pw)

print 'running remote command'

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.close()

for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print '%s$: %s' % (host, line)
    if outfile != None:
        f_outfile.write("%s\n" %line)

for line in stderr.read().splitlines():
    print '%s$: %s' % (host, line + "\n")
    if outfile != None:
        f_outfile.write("%s\n" %line)

ssh.close()

if outfile != None:
    f_outfile.close()

print 'connection to %s closed' %host

except:
   e = sys.exc_info()[1]
   print '%s' %e
```

works fine when then remote command doesn't need a tty. i found an invoke_shell example [Nested SSH session with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko).  i'm not happy with this solution, because if a server has an prompt that isn't specified in my script -> infinite loop or a specified prompt in the script is a string in the return text -> not all data will be received. is there a better solution maybe where stdout and stderr are send back like in my script?

Comment: Mind that this answer does not use an SSH key and therefore a pw is needed. With SSH key, you do not need a pw and pass the key_filename parameter instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is extensive paramiko API documentation you can find at: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/index.html

I use the following method to execute commands on a password protected client:

```
import paramiko

nbytes = 4096
hostname = 'hostname'
port = 22
username = 'username' 
password = 'password'
command = 'ls'

client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)

stdout_data = []
stderr_data = []
session = client.open_channel(kind='session')
session.exec_command(command)
while True:
    if session.recv_ready():
        stdout_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
    if session.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
    if session.exit_status_ready():
        break

print 'exit status: ', session.recv_exit_status()
print ''.join(stdout_data)
print ''.join(stderr_data)

session.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: instead of `data_block` one should use `session.recv(4096)` and `session.recv_stderr(4096)` for example (where did the `data_block` come?).

Comment: You are correct, the data_block was as you described(recv/recv_stderr) but I deleted those lines by accident.

Comment: As of May, 2015, the Paramiko docs are [here](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/index.html)

Comment: As of Dec. 2015, Paramiko docs (version 1.16) are here: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/index.html

Comment: there is something wrong in this code: it works but sometimes the response is not complete Clipped.

Comment: do this code do the same ??? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28411997/4691734

Answer (score 37):

There is something wrong with the accepted answer, it sometimes (randomly) brings a clipped response from server. I do not know why, I did not investigate the faulty cause of the accepted answer because this code worked perfectly for me:

```
import paramiko

ip='server ip'
port=22
username='username'
password='password'

cmd='some useful command' 

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
outlines=stdout.readlines()
resp=''.join(outlines)
print(resp)

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('some really useful command')
outlines=stdout.readlines()
resp=''.join(outlines)
print(resp)
```

Comment: I have also seen this, it's like a race condition w/ exit_status_ready() and recv_ready()

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking to capture exit code using above method - stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

Comment: There is a exception: key cannot be used for signing

Answer (score 0):

The code of @ThePracticalOne is great for showing the usage except for one thing:
**Somtimes** the output would be incomplete.(`session.recv_ready()` turns true after the `if session.recv_ready():` while `session.recv_stderr_ready()` and `session.exit_status_ready()` turned true before entering next loop)

so my thinking is to retrieving the data when it is ready to exit the session.

```
while True:
if session.exit_status_ready():
while True:
    while True:
        print "try to recv stdout..."
        ret = session.recv(nbytes)
        if len(ret) == 0:
            break
        stdout_data.append(ret)

    while True:
        print "try to recv stderr..."
        ret = session.recv_stderr(nbytes)
        if len(ret) == 0:
            break
        stderr_data.append(ret)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless SSH worked for me

```
import paramiko

def connect_SSH():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    username = '<uname>'
    port = <port-no>
    ip = '<ip-address>'
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip,port,username)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('<cmd>')
    outlines = stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    print(resp) 
connect_SSH()
```

Answer (score 0):

ThePracticalOne - you are hero!
I had  problems with exec_command (which is a member of Client)
I tried to run powershell commands over ssh on Windows server, and only your example  with

```
client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)
```

and

```
 while True:
        if session.recv_ready():
            stdout_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
        if session.recv_stderr_ready():
            stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
        if session.exit_status_ready():
            break
```

helped to me!

Answer (score -1):

```
###### Use paramiko to connect to LINUX platform############
import paramiko

ip='server ip'
port=22
username='username'
password='password'
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)

--------Connection Established-----------------------------

######To run shell commands on remote connection###########
import paramiko

ip='server ip'
port=22
username='username'
password='password'
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)


stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
outlines=stdout.readlines()
resp=''.join(outlines)
print(resp) # Output
```

Comment: Refer to :     Refer to : https://github.com/sarthakjain1811/Python-Scripts/blob/master/Connect%20to%20remote%20linux%20connection%20and%20run%20shell%20commands