# Why this linux command in python wont open xterm terminal?

Tags: python, linux, testing, debian, xterm

I have the following line of code

```
print linuxCommand.execute_ssh_command("xterm -e \"cd /home/;./lapras.sh; bash\" &", True, False)
```

It wont open the graphic terminal,I can do it manually with a script or running another script, also the test is running on a Debian session in a server.

Answer (score 0):

Print a command on terminal is not the same thing that use him.

You can use subprocess to call a bash command on python:

`import subprocess
subprocess.call("date")`

Your bash command use args so you can use subprocess like that:

```
subprocess.call(["command1", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

More info: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/

Comment: Hello the thing is that the subprocess executes on windows and it should do it in the debian sesion, do you know how i can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your problem, do u want to send a terminal command to another machine, that is it?

Comment: Yes, I am on a windows computer and I want to open xterm and send a command in another computer with debian

Comment: Ok, you can use paramiko third-party library, this library basically uses SSH-protocol to send terminal commands to another computer. With that you will no longer need an graphical interface. More info: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko
Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411960/execute-a-command-on-remote-machine-in-python