# Module not callable with remote server connection

Tags: python, remote-server

My code is here:

```
from pypsexec import client    
import os    
import time    
import sys    
import paramiko    
host = '192.168.x.x'    
user = 'xxxxx'    
pass1 = 'xxxxx'    
c = client(host, username=user, password=pass1, encrypt=False, port=139)    
c.connect()    
try:    
    c.create_service()    
    stdout = c.run_executable("cmd.exe", arguments="xxxx")    
finally:    
    c.cleanup()    
    c.remove_service()    
    c.disconnect()
```

And it gives an error:

> Module not callable with remote server connection

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21324981/6013016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you to understand the error:

```
x = 1
print x()
```

`x` is not a callable object, but you are trying to call it as if it was it. This example produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: hi Sherzod i am new to python what is the other module other than paramiko to comment to remote server to run commands and capture result any script for reference plz

Comment: This is actually another question. Even so, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411960/execute-a-command-on-remote-machine-in-python) out. And please mark my answer as correct if it was helpful :)