# Best ways to do ssh and scp in Python?

Tags: python, ssh, scp

What are the best ways to do ssh and scp in Python? I want to eliminate an Apache Ant build like we are doing in Java.

Comment: try Fabric: http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paramiko`. it is one of the best python package for ssh and scp.

link: [python paramiko ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745138/python-paramiko-ssh)

http://www.paramiko.org/