# How can I run a local python script on a remote host and communicate with it using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

I'm trying to write a Python program that executes a **local** Python script on a remote host and lets me communicate with the script when it's running.

My code currently consists of the two files `run.py` and `remote.py`:

`run.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "remote.py")) as scriptf:
    node_script = scriptf.read()

sess = sp.Popen(["ssh", "remote_host", "/usr/bin/python -"], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = sess.communicate(node_script)
print(stdout, stderr)
sess.stdin.write("Print me this!\n")
```

`remote.py`:

```
import sys

print("Hello!")

while True:
    line = input()
    print(line)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
('Hello!\n', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 10, in <module>
    sess.stdin.write("Print me this!\n")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Is there any way I can pipe a python script into a remote Python interpreter like this AND be able to use something like `input()` on that script later? How could I change my example to work?

Comment: this is basically the use-case of a REST API.  If you want to ssh into the remote host and run commands on it I would recommend [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#run-function) or maybe you want to look into Ansible?

Comment: There is a similar thing on github to do this . https://github.com/syedjafer/Serial-Activity/blob/master/kill.py

Comment: @syedjafer: `kill.py` seems to copy files first, which I don't want to.
@monkut: I'm not looking for an ansible or pexpect solution. I'm aware that there are other ways to run commands on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using paramiko-sftp [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635131/paramikos-sshclient-with-sftp) to transfer python script to remote system and login to remote system using paramiko-ssh [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745138/python-paramiko-ssh) to run the script on remote system.

Comment: Of course I could transfer the script beforehand, but I'd rather not create any files on the remote host for some reasons. Thank you for the suggestion, though. (Also, I need a solution requiring nothing but a stock python installation, without additional packages).