# Python: How can remote from my local pc to remoteA to remoteb to remote c using Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I would like to know how to to jump from one remote server to another remote server using paramiko. I want to ssh from my local pc to remote-A then from remote-A to remote-B and from remote- B to remote-C.

```
import paramiko
def connect(ip, usr, psw):
 client = paramiko.SSHClient()
 client.load_host_keys('/home/dgomez/.ssh/known_hosts')
 client.connect(ip, username=usr, password=psw)
 return client

host1 = connect('192.168.1.2', 'username', 'password')
# Here I'm connect to remote-A
```

Now I would to know how can I connect from Remote-A to Remote-B.

Comment: You might want to check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of the question mentioned above. Also you should really check your architecture or how you server management if you have to do something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for pexpect module it is very useful for you http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect
and and pexpect module simplified in pxssh module that very good for remote login http://dsnra.jpl.nasa.gov/software/Python/site-packages/Contrib/pxssh.html
simple code:

```
import pxssh
host = pxssh.pxssh
host.login('hostname','username','password')
host.sendline('command')#'ls'
print host.before
```