# Use Pexpect or expect for a ssh task， and how to capture errors

Tags: linux, expect, pexpect

I want to use an expect or Pexpect file to automate a shell command
like:

```
 for host in HostList:
      ssh -t kitty@host 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'
```

if I manually input the command, there are 3 possibilities
for case **2**, I have to input a `yes`, for the other cases I don't need to input anything
password is not needed.

**1)**

```
   [kitty@goeland kitty]$ ssh -t kitty@202.171.61.205 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' 
    nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
    Connection to 202.171.61.205 closed.
```

**2)**

```
    [kitty@goeland kitty]$ ssh -t kitty@202.171.61.205 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' 
    The authenticity of host '202.171.61.205 (202.171.61.205)' can't be established.
    RSA key fingerprint is ff:0b:9c:a9:72:52:8f:53:0d:04:d5:ea:d9:3c:56:37.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Warning: Permanently added '202.171.61.205' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
    Connection to 202.171.61.205 closed.
```

**3)** 
       different errors, at the moment I haven't got yet

for **3**, I want to know the errors

so how to use `expect` or `Pexpect` to do this?
preferably `Pexpect`
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have use pxssh modules, this is the **This class extends pexpect.spawn to specialize setting up SSH connections.
This adds methods for login, logout, and expecting the shell prompt.** that module handle in automatically in your **2 question** 'yes'

example code:-
[Python: How can remote from my local pc to remoteA to remoteb to remote c using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818328/python-how-can-remote-from-my-local-pc-to-remotea-to-remoteb-to-remote-c-using/15831027#15831027)

and cache your error login:- 
sample code is like

```
host = pxssh.pxssh()
host.login (hostname, username, password)
host.logfile = open(/tmp/logfile.txt, "w")
host.sendline("ls -l")
```

open the **logfile.txt** your terminal output are store in text file