# Paramiko - ssh command over ssh

Tags: python, paramiko

Is it possible by using paramiko or other library to connect via ssh to a machine and then connect to another also via ssh? I'm thinking of using pexpect combined but have no idea how to do that.

PC A running python -> Gateway B -> Endpoint C 
Execute SSH command on C and get response.
Execute SSH command on B and still get response.

Later edit 1:
I cannot use keys with no authentication.

Later edit 2:
One solution would be to start the ssh server on B and listen on multiple ports and then port forward to C

Comment: Do you mean taking first connection from A to B and then continuing from B to C or first taking connection A to B and then A to C?

Comment: ssh from A to B and then continue with ssh from B to C....finally get the response of commands to A given on C. B is just a gateway to C. hope this explains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested SSH session with Paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko)