# How can I use Paramiko to SSH from A -> B, then from B -> C seamlessly?

Tags: python, ssh, virtual-machine, paramiko, network-security

I have several computers running several virtual machines on bridged connections. I want to create a script that ultimately allows me to SSH into any computer, change some files, and then SSH into another VM or computer from that computer.

How can I use Paramiko to SSH from computer A to computer B, and then from computer B to computer C (without exiting the connection from A first)? Does this change at all when dealing with virtual machines on the same LAN using bridged connections?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Paramiko to do this a few times before, it's been a little while and I don't have those old scripts at hand for reference, but take a look at this same question on SO:

[Nested SSH session with Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911690/nested-ssh-session-with-paramiko)

I used [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) however, and it's probably a better way of doing it at first glance.

If I get a chance tomorrow I might be able to find the scripts I wrote and post some sample code.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at pexpect now. I saw that old post and didn't find it particularly useful.

This is a long-term project I'm working on, so if you find the scripts tomorrow I'll certainly be checking.

Comment: Yeah, the stuff in that post ain't pretty tbh. I'll give it a look tomorrow and see if I can find it, I wrote it at an old job and might not have taken it with me, but I did definitely save some paramiko stuff so I might be able to remember the jist of it.

Comment: I can't see the old scripts I had, soz. If I have time this week I'll write something up as an example; I'll definitely need to use it again in the near future anyway, so I'm happy to go over it. I can't promise I'll have time though...

Comment: Not a problem -- I'll be checking regardless! Thanks.